# d3js: multiple bar graphs arranged in a specific order

Tags: graph, d3.js

I wanna draw multiple bar graphs and arrange them at specific locations using d3js. Basically something like this:

[image]

I have drawn individual bar graphs earlier, but not sure how to draw multiple little bar graphs and place them as shown in the pic.

Any suggestions or links would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To create several charts as shown in the figure, you will need to have a data structure that allows you to compute the layout for the charts. The data structure could be something like:

```
var data = [
    {row: 0, col: 0, data: [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 2}, ...]},
    {row: 0, col: 1, data: [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 3}, ...]},
]
```

Then, you will need to implement your charts as [reusable charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/), so you can generate any number of charts without duplicating code and following the D3 style. Assuming that you have a reusable chart `barchart`, you will need to configure it, create container elements for your charts, and invoke your chart:

```
// Create and configure the barchars
var chart = barchart()
    .width(100)
    .height(100);

// Create the SVG element and set its size...

// Create a group for each element in the data array
var gcharts = svg.selectAll('g.chart').data(data)
   .enter().append('g')
   .attr('class', 'chart');


// Translate the groups using the row and column
gcharts.attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + 100 * d.row + ',' + d.col + ')';
});

// Create the charts, using the data bound to each selection.
gcharts.call(barchart);
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for that ! I am got some idea how to go about it now :)

Comment: I had a look at [link](https://github.com/backstopmedia/D3Edge/blob/master/code/Chapter04/ResuableBarChart/script.js) and [link](http://bl.ocks.org/cloudshapes/6003578), but I got really confused, these examples provide predefined svg containers to their chart calling function; but with my data the svg elements depend on the row and col value, how does that work ?? Its my first time dealing with reusable charts :(

Comment: You can either create one SVG element for each chart or have one SVG element for each one. In any case, you will need to understand the reusable chart pattern to do something like that. Consider working on that a couple of days, you can ask if there is something specific that you don't understand.

Comment: I am going through some examples of reusable charts to develop an understanding of the concept. I would like to have one SVG element for the whole chart and each bar graph placed in it. In your example code above, could u plz explain how grouping with gcharts work ??

Comment: SVG groups are container for other elements. In the example, a group is added and translated for each chart. Using the code shown above, the chart's inner elements will be added to each group. Mike Bostock's article [How selections work](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) can help you to better understand the code.